# Correct syntax for adding CSS with JQuery for additional properties

Tags: jquery, css

Basically I want to use JQuery to manipulate the CSS when the page loads.

I want to add this CSS:

```
animation: drawcircle 1.5s 2
```

How do I break that up to attach via Jquery CSS?

`.css ("animation", "Drawcircle 1.5s 2")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it either you use class toggle or manual depending on your needs.

```
// The class toggle style
// JS
element.classList.add("animate"); // to start
element.classList.remove("animate"); // to stop

// css
thelement.animate {
   animation: drawcircle 1.5s 2;
}
```

OR

```
// jQuery
$(element).addClass("animate"); // to start
$(element).removeClass("animate"); // to stop

// css
thelement.animate {
   animation: drawcircle 1.5s 2;
}
```

OR

```
// the manual style
// JS
element.style.animation = "drawcircle 1.5s 2";
```

OR

```
// jQuery
$(element).css("animation", "spin 1.5s infinite");
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
element.css('animation-name', 'drawcircle');
element.css('animation-duration', '4s');
```

Where

> drawcircle

is the animation you defined in an @keyframes definition.

Here is an example of how to draw a circle with pure CSS:
[Draw a circle with pure CSS](https://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/)

You can use the mask element in that example to start the animation like:

```
mask.css('animation-play-state', 'running');
```